# Spring JPA Concurrency Transactional or Lock

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, concurrency, spring-transactions, locks

As per ACID properties, `@Transactional` should handle `Isolation` by default. For `Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ`, it should prevent dirty read, non repeatable read problems. I'm using MySQL database, Spring boot 3.2.3, Java 17

I'm trying to handle concurrency since a 3 days. Nothing is working.

I have a `Product` Entity, I'm trying to do `addQuantity(id){q+10}` and `mulQuantity(id){q*2}` which updates quantity field.

To demonstrate concurrency I'm trying to run `two threads` one adds other multiplies

`My Expectation is that:`
Either it should add first and multiply next or vice versa, but in any case the updates should not be `overriden`

But with my approaches it is getting overriden

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/run")
    ResponseEntity<?> run() {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        executorService.submit(() -> productService.addQuantity(1L));
        executorService.submit(() -> productService.mulQuantity(1L));
        executorService.submit(() -> productService.addQuantity(2L));
        executorService.submit(() -> productService.mulQuantity(2L));

        executorService.shutdown();

        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
    }
```

Service

```
@Transactional
    public void addQuantity(Long id) {
        Product p = productRepository.findById(id).get();
        p.setQuantity(p.getQuantity() + 10);
        log.info("ADD id {}, q {}", id, p.getQuantity());
        productRepository.save(p);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void mulQuantity(Long id) {
        Product p = productRepository.findById(id).get();
        p.setQuantity(p.getQuantity() * 2);
        log.info("MUL id {}, q {}", id, p.getQuantity());
        productRepository.save(p);
    }
```

Entity

```
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private int quantity;
}
```

My Approaches:

1. I think this is Optimistic locking, `@Vesrion`, Got this `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` which is ok, but not concurrent..

```
@Version
private int version;
```

2. Adding Isolation level at add, multiply method, which is by default the same, overrides it

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
```

3. Only `working` way was, pessimistic lock on repository

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Optional<Product> findById(Long id);
```

4. Did not try `Isolation.SERIALIZATION`, but I think it will work but not efficient

My questions:

`1)I want to know, is adding @Transactional not sufficient to handle concurrency?` (when I run two different transactions in mysql command line, it either waits or give dead lock, it works very well) But why there is an issue in Spring boot.

`2)Do we really need to handle locking separately, no way out?`

`3) Ways to handle concurrency with transaction, with lock`

`4) Except for rollback what is use of @Transactional?`

Open to provide more details, please help me out.